# How to make bootstrap navbar expand when content forces a line break?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am using the bootstrap navbar with fixed top.  Everything works fine on a medium/large screen but on smaller screens the header in the navbar breaks to two lines and therefore lies partially outside the nav.  Is there anyway to make the navbar expand depending on screen size so the content still fits?  Whilst doing this what is the correct way to get the screen size? (I've come across a variety of opinions on this)

Comment: provide a jsfiddle plz

Comment: If you need to detect screen/viewport size in JS, check http://codepen.io/dih/full/ivECj

Comment: Thanks, I found it was easier to change the content if the screen width was below a certain size than worry about trying to adjust the nav